# Does a Durable General Power of Attorney extent to voting rights?

Tags: united-states, washington, voting, power-of-attorney

If a person had a durable general power of attorney for another person as a result of that person being disabled *but not incompetent*, would it be legal to sign a ballot and cast a vote on their behalf?

There is another question with good answers about proxy voting for someone who is mentally incompetent here:  [POA & Proxy voting](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/does-power-of-attorney-extend-to-voting-in-an-election)

However, this scenario is the opposite.  It this case the person is able to communicate their preferences, but unable to fill in the marks or sign their name to a mail-in ballot.  (the only option in Washington State)

Answer (score 0):

In Vermont, if the voter is able to indicate his or her preferences, the question of whether a person with a POA for the voter can vote on the principal's behalf can be avoided. As explained in a [Vermont Secretary of State website](https://sos.vermont.gov/elections/voters/accessible-voting/), the voter may bring someone to assist to the polling place, or an election official may mark the ballot in accordance with the voter's instructions. The ["Vermont Justice of the Peace Guide"](https://sos.vermont.gov/elections/voters/early-absentee-voting/) explains that the ballot may be delivered to the home of the voter with a disability by two Justices of the Peace and returned to the polling place.